# Reusing Object in IOS

Tags: objective-c, uikit

In other languages I can do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
{
    Object obj = new Object();
    UI.Display(obj.text = array[i]);
}
```

and I will get a display with multiple objects with different text.

However when programming in Objective-C in Xcode 4+ with ARC on, there is no 'new' initializer. So when I do something like:

```
for(NSString *s in testArray) {
    NSArray nibObjects =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Page" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView subview = [nibObjects lastObject];
    ... //Add some custom images or text
    [scrollView addSubview:subview];
}
```

I only get the one view. I assume because it is still referencing the same memory location. When I use this in a scrollview with say 5 different views, only the last on works. The rest are blank.

Any suggestions on how I am supposed to reuse a custom nib layout in the scrollview? It needs to be dynamic as the number I add changes.

**-EDIT-**

Another try with no result

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    nibObjects =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Page" owner:self options:nil];

    //Move frame location
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview = [nibObjects lastObject];
    [scrollView addSubview:subview];
}
 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 4, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Both of those caused a NSInvalidArgumentException

Comment: It's not really clear what you're expecting to happen. If you need to create a new view, then you can certainly do so.

Comment: The nib is a custom layout. I want to be able to use that layout an x number of times in a scrollview. However when I do so it just created on view and the rest are blank. I have no idea why it doesn't make the x number of separate views.

Comment: There's only one nib, and one set of objects in that nib.

Comment: Sorry I am new so I hope I don't cause any frustration. How would I dynamically create more instances of the nib? So if the forloop runs X times then it will have X different instances. Re-allocating and initiating doesn't seam to do it.

Comment: @DominikHadl: `new` is a class method on `NSObject` and `UIView` doesn't implement `NSCopying`.

Comment: Actually, it seems I'm wrong; `loadNibNamed:...` creates new copies of everything each time. Every copy will have the same position, though, and thus they'll overlap. Are you changing the frame of the newer views as you add them.

Comment: Josh, I have added an edit of what I am currently trying, I am creating a frame and moving to the next position. (Testing with 4 slots) However it ends with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no 'new' initializer

In Objective-C you initialise objects by sending the `alloc` message to the class and then an `init...` message to the returned instance. If you don't know how to initialise an object, please read basic Objective-C literature first.

```
NSArray nibObjects =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Page" owner:self options:nil];
UIView subview = [nibObjects lastObject];
```

`loadNibNamed` returns <strike>a `BOOL`, not an `NSArray` and even if it returned an `NSArray` it would return</strike> a pointer to an `NSArray` object. Suppose you actually had a pointer to an `NSArray` of `UIViews`, `[nibObjects lastObject]` would always return the same object (and again, it would return a pointer to `UIView`).

Comment: Any suggestion on where to go from here? It was very informative but I can't fathom a solution to my problem.

Comment: You're right, I looked at the wrong docs. Fixed.

Comment: @Brianjs: I'd suggest properly learning the language and the frameworks first. THen you can ask specific questions here on SO.